# How do I modify a list without inputting an exact variable for the modification I'm making?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm in an intro programming course and struggling a bit with lists in Python. The following problem is from my textbook and I'm having an issue getting my code to pass both tests:

Modify short_names by deleting the first element and changing the last element to Joe. Sample output from given program:
['Sam', 'Ann', 'Joe']

Here is my code (which passes the test for the sample output):

```
short_names = ['Gertrude', 'Sam', 'Ann', 'Joseph']
short_names[1] = ['Sam' , 'Ann' , 'Joe']
short_names = short_names[1]
my_list = short_names[2:4]


print(short_names)
```

When other names are substituted in for the original short_names (ex: ['Jessica' , 'Erin' , 'Max', 'Josepfine'] then my code fails to execute properly. I think that having the actual names in my "short_names[1]" variable is the reason for this. I'm just not sure how to fix it. Any direction/advice would be great. Thanks!

Comment: `short_names[0]` always refers to the first element, regardless of what is stored there.  Similarly, `short_names[-1]` always refers to the last element.

Comment: You should do what the instructions say - delete the first element, and change the last one. Not replace the entire list. If you don't know how to do that, the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) or the [SO docs](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/209/list#t=201707152121229967559) are good places to find out.

Answer (score 3):

```
short_names = ['Gertrude', 'Sam', 'Ann', 'Joseph']

# remove first element
del short_names[0]

# set last element to 'Joe'
short_names[-1] = 'Joe'
```

Comment: Thank you@john This makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't hard code the names when you do `short_names[1] = ['Sam' , 'Ann' , 'Joe']`.
Instead, do this:

```
short_names = short_names[1:] # removes first element
short_names[-1] = "Joe" # set last element
```

Comment: Thank you! @frozen This makes way more sense.